# How to add a Scrollable List Group to right of Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to modify the Bootstrap carousel to display a scrollable list group with item details on the right-side for an Angular app.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Make the carousel a row with the list and image as columns, use table
  and table-cell properties.
- Use flexbox property to make the list
  group shrink to height of image.
- Nesting (see code below) and
  inheriting max-height for the list group from the parent.

Of course, each of these approaches might be valid and I didn't implement them properly - I mostly work on backend so it's entirely possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I'm only looking for help with styling and I'd prefer to avoid jQuery.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

  <!-- Bootstrap responsive list group -->
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
      <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
        <small>3 days ago</small>
      </div>
      <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
    </a>
    <!-- Omitted Additional List Group Items -->
  </div>
</div>
```